# How do I print the path of a file in a different directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, path

I know that if you have a file `one.txt` in `~/Documents` and you `cd ~/Documents` then `realpath one.txt` will print:

`~/Documents/one.txt`.

However what if you want to print the path of a file in a different directory. For example, `cd a/b` and there is a file `two.txt` in directories `a2/b2` then how does a person print the absolute path of `two.txt` by just passing `two.txt` to a command.

Looking to do something like `realpath two.txt` that works from a different directory.

Answer (score 3):

Just give `realpath` the relative path from the current directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/myself/local/build/shell-toolbox
$ realpath ../../../.profile
/home/myself/.profile
```

The GNU `realpath` utility would not be able to find my `.profile` file, or produce the absolute path for it, without me giving it a hint about where it was located. In your case, you could potentially have any number of files called `two.txt`, so `realpath` must at least be given a relative path from the current directory to be able to give an absolute pathname for the file.

In a Unix filesystem, a file is uniquely identified by a *pathname* (either relative or absolute).  A *filename* can not uniquely identify any file other than one of the files in the current directory.

To locate all regular files called `two.txt` in or under your home directory, and get their pathnames relative to `$HOME`:

```
find "$HOME" -type f -name two.txt
```

Comment: That could work but what if you cannot give `realpath` the relative path because the file is in a different branch. For example instead of `.profile` you wanted to query a file in `/etc`? Perhaps `realpath` does not have this functionality because the developers wanted to avoid printing the paths of files with the same name but in practice how many files can be identical in name?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Files are identified _uniquely_ by pathnames. Either a relative pathname from the current directory, or an absolute pathname from the root directory. A _filename_ can not uniquely identify a file other than in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, may be I should rephrase my question. Can a relative path name from the current directory be used with `realpath` for a file that is on a different branch of the directory tree?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia The answer is yes. See my answer above for an example.